# unable to read returned data from function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I am using reactJS.

I have a child component which looks like:

```
const Child = ({callback}) => {
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        console.log(await callback()); //callback returns an async value
    }
    return (
        <div> some stuff here </div>
    )
}
export default Child;
```

I use my Child component on parent component like :

```
const Parent = () => {
    const sendSomeDataToServer = () => {
        axios({
             //some stuff here...
        })
        .then((res) => return {serverInfo: 'OK'})
        .catch((err) => {
            if(err.response.status < 500)
                return {serverInfo: 'e.response.data'}
            else
                return {serverInfo: 'Unexpected error'}
        }
    }

    return (
        <Child callback={sendSomeDataToServer} />
    )
}
export default Parent;
```

but I don't know why the returned value by `sendSomeDataToServer` is always undefined...

Looks like await not working as expected, any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add a return statement before Axios

you are not returning anything from sendSomeDataToServer function.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const sendSomeDataToServer = () => {
      return  axios({
             //some stuff here...
        })
        .then((res) =>  ({serverInfo: 'OK'}))
        .catch((err) => {
            if(err.response.status < 500)
                return {serverInfo: 'e.response.data'}
            else
                return {serverInfo: 'Unexpected error'}
        }
    }

    return (
        <Child callback={sendSomeDataToServer} />
    )
}
```

Comment: did you remove on purpose the `return` statement inside `then` ?

Comment: if you use the arrow function you don't need a return statement.